# CSRF fix in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I need the fix for CSRF flaw for aspx page. The code is like this -

ASPX -

```html
<asp:Content runat='server'>
<asp:Panel runat='server'>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Username" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit"
                            OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" CssClass="Resizable" />
  </tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

ASPX.cs -

```html
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //Code here
        }
```

Now while inserting <%@ Html.AntiForgeryToken() %> at the top throws error "The server block is not well formed". So how should I proceed with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You're using webforms here. They already have anti-xsrf set up in the template of the master page (I think it's tucked in with all of the viewstate data).

So as long as you are using a master page then you needn't worry.

If you're not using a master page just build your own using session state, a hidden field and a guid. I've taken the below from http://willseitz-code.blogspot.com/2013/06/cross-site-request-forgery-for-web-forms.html

Your hiddenfield...

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="antiforgery" runat="server"/>
```

The code that does the work server side...

```
public static class AntiforgeryChecker
{
    public static void Check(Page page, HiddenField antiforgery)
    {
        if (!page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Guid antiforgeryToken = Guid.NewGuid();
            page.Session["AntiforgeryToken"] = antiforgeryToken;
            antiforgery.Value = antiforgeryToken.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Guid stored = (Guid) page.Session["AntiforgeryToken"];
            Guid sent = new Guid(antiforgery.Value);

            if (sent != stored)
            {
                throw new SecurityException("XSRF Attack Detected!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the following in your `Page_Load` method in code behind...

```
AntiforgeryChecker.Check(this, antiforgery);
```

Comment: Error - The name 'antiforgery' does not exist in the current context for AntiforgeryChecker.Check(this, antiforgery);

Comment: @AnkurRai have you set the hiddenfield on the page with runat='server'? You should be able to then reference it in page load

Comment: Yes I have added. But I got alternate solution to add SameSite attribute in config. This works and less confusion.

Comment: You should just use a master page in all honesty. There's no point trying to reinvent the wheel